# Обновить строки если нет определенного значения

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Добавляю к последним 10 записям в столбец "read" данные так:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `read`= CONCAT(`read`, ',$user_id') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Как сделать проверку, если в "read" уже есть $user_id, то тогда обновлять не нужно?

Comment: связи многие-ко-многим реализуются с помощью доп. таблицы, а не хранением списка ID в строке

Comment: У меня 2 пользователя всего, больше не будет. Для двух, думаю, можно так сделать?

Comment: @Евгений не надо так делать

Comment: Надо сразу делать правильно.

Comment: Кто поможет в моем случае?

Comment: Вам еще писать запрос на удаление пользователя из этого поля. То же будете спрашивать как это сделать ? Поле со списком привносит необходимость реализации на SQL множества вещей, на которое он вообще не рассчитан. В итоге вы пишите в 5 раз больше сложного, плохо сопровождаемого кода, чем было бы, если бы вы вынесли этот список в отдельную таблицу. Так что тут дело не в количестве пользователей у вас в системе, а в количестве лишней работы, которую вы находите на свою голову. Что до ответа на вопрос: как вы ищете пользователей в этом поле ? - вот прямо такой where и добавляйте в update

Comment: а еще ваш update не предусматривает ситуации, что поле до него было пустым (или может вообще null)

Comment: И кстати, если вы уверены, что у вас всего два пользователя, то можно вообще ввести поле типа int и хранить наличие или отсутствие нужного пользователя просто битом в этом поле. будет на порядок проще. правда больше 32 пользователей использовать будет невозможно, но ведь 32 гораздо больше двух ...

Comment: @Mike, даже если я свяжу 2 таблицы, как мне 1 запросом обновить N строк?

Comment: А вам надо будет не обновлять строки, а добавлять их и тогда запрос будет вида `insert ignore into table_users(id, user_id) select id, $user_id from table order by id desc limit 10` (ignore указал на случай если такой пользователь уже где то окажется, у вас же будет на этой таблице первичный ключ состоящий из полей id, user_id)

Comment: @Евгений, а можно хоть в скользь описать что за задача стоит перед вами? Возможно вам нужна другая структуру данных с которой будет проще работать

Comment: @Yuriy Prokopets чат для двоих. На сайт никто попадать не будет кроме меня и еще 1 человека, в индексацию тоже попадать ничего не будет.

Comment: @Евгений, тогда создайте 2 колонки `readUser1` и `readUser2` и сможете отмечать кто прочитал сообщение и выбирать сообщения которые еще не прочил кто-то из участников диалога.